# Stripping down text from files

Tags: perl

I need to strip down all `console` statements (`console.log, console.error`, etc) from all javascript files in a folder. How do I do that?

trying this:

```
perl -pi -e "s/console.(.*);/g" *.js
```

doesn't work properly. I have to delete everything that starts with console. and end with closing parenthesis, not semicolon

Answer (score 1):

Supposing that all your `console` commands are in separate lines you can try something like this

```
perl -pi -e "s/^\s*console\.\(.*?\);\s*$//g" *.js
```

Comment: @Paulchenkiller I didn't forget it. I think the OP wants to delete the whole line

Answer (score 1):

Not tried but what about a short `sed`?

For example:

```
find . -name "*.js" -exec sed -i "s/console\.[^\)]+\);//g" '{}' \;
```